# Multiple HTTP POST request when user only clicked once

Tags: apache, http, networking, servlets, service-provider

We have a curious situation with http referrer and response.
Our application is a J2EE with a WEB and EJB project.  Working fine for years.

Recently, from one specific location, when user click to submit, our EJB sysout picked up trace that there was more than one submit (POST request) resulting in a null pointer.  Our button have been designed to be disabled after it has been clicked.  We are not sure how a subsequent request can possibly happen.  In this simulation of the problem, we click once and there is only one user in the system.

Since this only occur when we connect from a particular ISP.  We do not experience multiple request from other ISP locations.  So we are suspecting that the ISP may have in advertently trigger a resubmit.  But we are not sure.  What else can we do to trace the root cause of this problem.

Thanks for your help.

## Update on 12-Apr

We have installed wireshark to trace the signal from the browser side. We notice that the browser concern makes a "retry" after every 11 or 12 minutes.  Would this be a normal browser behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps you are doing something very wrong ? We would need to see code. The question is way to generalized and impossible to answer at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @adam.    We replicate the situation by creating a code that does nothing but loop for 30min.  Then we trigger the call with a JUNITEE call. This isolated the problem from our codes or UI.  And from that particular location, we observed 6 calls. Strangely, the calls even continued being made after the system timed out. We are looking at the configuration of the WAS IHS plugin. But not very sure what to look for. There were traces of 401 errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think we have found the cause of the problem.  It is explained by by this https://blogs.oracle.com/ravello/beware-http-requests-automatic-retries

It is something in the HTTP spec
"If an HTTP/1.1 client sends a request which includes a request body, but which does not include an Expect request-header field with the "100-continue" expectation, and if the client is not directly connected to an HTTP/1.1 origin server, and if the client sees the connection close before receiving any status from the server, the client SHOULD retry the request. W3 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1